# How would you explicitly define the number type of a function's parameters?

Tags: functions, notation

Say I make a function $f$ that takes a parameter $a$, but I want to make sure that $a$ can only be $\mathbb{N}$, no $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ allowed (as an example), how would I write that in a clear and concise way?

Comment: $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be a function whose domain is $\Bbb N$.

---

Let $a\in \Bbb N$ and define $f(a)=\cdots$.

---

Let $f\colon \Bbb N\to X$ be a function, for some set $X$.